# Label in Tkinter: change the text

Tags: python, tkinter, label

I'm trying to change the value of the text of a label in tkinter, I'm using `label.config()` but it seems that the previous value still appears on the screen with the new value.

This is the code that I'm using:

[image: This is the code that I'm using]

This is the result, the previous and the new text are together:

[image: This is the result, the previous and the new text are together]

Comment: You can use **.set()** to change a label text value, For example : ``description_label.set("Profile 2...")``

Comment: Try to avoid using ```if....if``` for the same context. ```if....elif....else``` should be used.

Comment: Please provide actual, copy-pasteable code in your question, not screenshots.

Answer (score 3):

Whenever `select_description()` is executed, new label is created and put in same cell.  That is why there are overlapped text.

You need to create the label once outside the function:

```py
description_label = Label(frame1)
description_label.grid(row=4, column=0, columnspan=4)

def select_description(event):
    choice = list_profiles.get(ANCHOR)
    if choice == 1:
        description_label.config(text=...)
    elif choice == 2:
        description_label.config(text=...)
```

Answer (score 0):

Short way to do this. W/out using `==1` and `==2`.
snippet:

```
description_label = Label(frame1)
description_label.grid(row=4, column=0, columnspan=4)

def select_description(event):
     choice = list_profiles.get(ANCHOR)
    if choice:
        description_label.config(text=...)
    else:
        description_label.config(text=...)
```